# Write a sub class of Parcelable to another Parcel

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a class that implements `Parcelable` interface:

```
class A implements Parcelable {

}
```

I have another class `B` that contains an `A` object as an instance variable. In the `writeToPacel` inside class `B`, I want to write object `B` to the `Parcel`:

```
class B implements Parcelable{

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.write ??? 
    }
}
```

How can I write and read it?

Comment: Where is the `A object` inside B?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```
class B implements Parcelable{
//lets assume you have A as a data member 

A obj;
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeParcelable(obj , flags);

    }
}
```

if you want to read it use this

```
 obj = in.readParcelable(A.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: No need for casting :)

Comment: You can be even more precise: `obj = (A) in.<A>readParcelable(A.class.getClassLoader());`

Comment: Casting is not required at al!

Answer (score 11):

A better way to handle this that avoids reflexion would be to simply call the static creator in the target type like this:

```
this.amazingObject = AmazingObject.CREATOR.createFromParcel(in);
```

and write it to the `Parcelable` using `this.amazingObject.writeToParcel(Parcel, int)`

Internally, when calling `readParcelable(ClassLoader)` this happens:

```
public final <T extends Parcelable> T readParcelable(ClassLoader loader) {
    Parcelable.Creator<T> creator = readParcelableCreator(loader);
    if (creator == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (creator instanceof Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<?>) {
        return ((Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<T>)creator).createFromParcel(this, loader);
    }
    return creator.createFromParcel(this);
}
```

As you can see the last call of that method is just calling the right `Creator` but inside `readParcelableCreator` there is a whole lot of reflexion that we can avoid by just calling it directly.

This utility calls may be useful:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Parcels {

    public static void writeBoolean(Parcel dest, Boolean value) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (value != null && value ? 1 : 0));
    }

    public static Boolean readBoolean(Parcel in){
        return in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static void writeParcelable(Parcel dest, int flags, Parcelable parcelable) {
        writeBoolean(dest, parcelable == null);
        if (parcelable != null) {
            parcelable.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        }
    }

    public static <T extends Parcelable> T readParcelable(Parcel in, Parcelable.Creator<T> creator) {
        boolean isNull = readBoolean(in);
        return isNull ? null : creator.createFromParcel(in);
    }

}
```

Comment: It throws an exception when the object is null, while ``readParcelable`` handles this situation correctly

Comment: @dragoon What's the exception you get?

Comment: I end up using my own Parcel Util but thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
obj = (A)in.readParcelable(A.class.getClassLoader());
```

should change to:

```
obj = (A)in.readParcelable(B.class.getClassLoader());
```

I encountered the same problem and did several Google search, many webpage or tutorial suggests we use `A.class.getClassLoader()` because we are casting to A, but actually it is WRONG because you will get a null value, we must use `B.class.getClassLoader()` because the `codes are INSIDE class B`. I just did not know why but it can get the correct A object in this way.

Welcome to comment and verify!!