# how to parcel Object type in Parcelable class in Java

Tags: java, android, object, parcelable, parcel

How this class implements parcelable right. i cant do parcel Object type.String, Double,Integer,.. variables types sets to the Object type.

```
public class MyClass implements Parcelable {
    public String Name;
    public Object Value; //variables type to set

    protected MyClass(Parcel in) {
        Name = in.readString();
        //Value = in.?
    }

    public static final Creator<MyClass> CREATOR = new Creator<MyClass>() {
        @Override
        public MyClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyClass(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyClass[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(Name);
        //dest.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question, [android parcel example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) is quite simple to use. For an object, it must be a `Parcelable` instance and use `readParcelable`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably I am too late but this might help someone else looking for same.

Since the Object class does not implement Parcelable, a workaround is needed. A way which i got through this obstacle was by using GSON and serializing and de-serializing to String and from String.

For e.g:

```
public class MyClass implements Parcelable {
    public String Name;
    public Object Value; //variables type to set

    protected MyClass(Parcel in) {
        Name = in.readString();
        Value = new Gson().fromJson(in.readString(), Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(Name);
        dest.writeString(new Gson().toJson(Value));
    }

}
```

- When writing to parcel converting the Object (Serializing) using GSON to JSON String and writing it as a String to parcel.
- While reading from parcel reading the parcel as String and converting (Deserializing) it to Object class using Gson again.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Parcel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) documentation is quite explicit about what you can do, here is some idea.

You have the methods [`writeParcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeParcelable%28android.os.Parcelable,%20int%29) to do that, but you can't parcel an `Object` because `Object` doesn't implement `Parcelable`.

You need to define a `class` that implements `Parcelable` for your `value`.

```
public class MyClass implements Parcelable {
    public String name;
    public ParcelableValue value; //variables type to set
    ...

    
}

public class ParcelableValue implements Parcelable {
    ...
}
```

For a complete implementation, see [Write a sub class of Parcelable to another Parcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239343/write-a-sub-class-of-parcelable-to-another-parcel)

You also have [`writeValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue%28java.lang.Object%29) but this still have some condition :

- Any object that implements Serializable (but see writeSerializable(Serializable) for caveats). Note that all of the previous types have relatively efficient implementations for writing to a Parcel; having to rely on the generic serialization approach is much less efficient and should be avoided whenever possible.*

For the complete list, see the doc of the method